# list.h syntax errors that appear only when I use the code in a my C project

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am trying to develop some extra functionalities of https://github.com/ffnord/alfred/blob/master/vis/vis.c
Since that I am not familiar with Linux lists (list.h), I tried to follow [this list.h tutorial](http://www.roman10.net/2011/07/28/linux-kernel-programminglinked-list/). To do that I created a very simple test.c file and I imported also the mentioned [list.h file](https://github.com/ffnord/alfred/blob/master/list.h) of batman/alfred (by openmesh).

Alfred/batman Github code compiles flawlessly, but in the example code GCC complains about list.h.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token   list.h  /C_Linux_kernel_lists/src   line 68 C/C++ Problem



Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand    list.h  /C_Linux_kernel_lists/src   line 68 C/C++ Problem
```

So my question is: why GCC does not complain with upstream list.h code and it returns me those messages when I try to use the same code?

Attached source code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "list.h"

struct Person
{
    char name[30];
    unsigned int weight;
    unsigned char gender;
    struct list_head list;
};

int main()
{
    struct Person personList;
    LIST_HEAD_INIT(&personList.list);

    struct Person* aNewPersonPointer;

    aNewPersonPointer = malloc(sizeof(*aNewPersonPointer));
    strcpt(aNewPersonPointer->name, "roman10");
    aNewPersonPointer->weight = 130;
    aNewPersonPointer->gender = 1;
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&aNewPersonPointer->list);


    list_add(&aNewPersonPointer->list, &personList.list);

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] to get assistance on something like this.

Comment: FWIW clang doesn't like that line either. `test.c:18:5: error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'struct list_head *'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should be calling `INIT_LIST_HEAD` and not `LIST_HEAD_INIT`.  This is just a guess based on how the rest of the alfred code uses the list interface, `LIST_HEAD_INIT` is never used outside of list.h, but `INIT_LIST_HEAD` is in `main.c`, `recv.c` and `vis/vis.c`.

This is [pointed out in a comment on that tutorial](http://www.roman10.net/2011/07/28/linux-kernel-programminglinked-list/#comment-2242).

Comment: Spot on. `LIST_HEAD_INIT` is for use as a direct initializer (as opposed to an initialization *call*). And the only way you can use it that way is if you're just declaring a bare list head, in which case you should use `LIST_HEAD(name)`  anyway which already uses `LIST_HEAD_INIT` so you don't need to.